# How can you multithread methods within loops that take much time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, json.net

I am working on some code which has the goal of connecting to an API to get usernames.

Currently, I have the code working in a loop, to which arises the issue of runtime. Each "list of usernames" can be in the thousands, which can take hours to obtain them all. My goal is to figure out how to make it threaded, to allow multiple lookups at once.

Here is my code, and the important information needed to understand it:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public List<LeaderboardItem> LeaderboardList;
public LeaderboardItem LBItem;
public GetNames getNames;

public GetLeaderboardRuns(string GameCode, string Category, string Query)
{
    LeaderboardList = new List<LeaderboardItem>();

    var Client = new WebClient();

    try
    {
        var Data = Client.DownloadString($"{URL.BaseUrl}/leaderboards/{GameCode}/category/{Category}{Query}");

        foreach (var item in (JArray)JObject.Parse(Data)["data"]["runs"])
        {
            int place = (int)item["place"];

            // This next line looks up the username on the API.
            // This code takes several seconds per loop to complete.
            // It is returned as a list of strings.
            getNames = new GetNames(item["run"]["players"]); 

            double time = (double)item["run"]["times"]["primary_t"];

            LBItem = new LeaderboardItem
            {
                Rank = place,
                Name = getNames.names,
                Time = time
            };

            LeaderboardList.Add(LBItem);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error: {err.Message}", "Error!");
    }
}
```

Each `LeaderboardItem` looks as follows:

```
public class LeaderboardItem
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; set; }
}
```

My expected result should be that it isn't dependent on each loop to finish before beginning the next username lookup. However, I am inexperienced in multithreading in this manner, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, client-side threading never makes a web api that takes *hours* to produce a few thousand user names any more efficient.  "Hours" is remarkably long btw, you'll have to dig deeper to figure out why it takes *that* long.  Do contact the web site owner for support.  Also ask for a "top" query so you don't have to retrieve everything, a leader board does not have thousands of entries.

Comment: Here is one such leaderboard: https://www.speedrun.com/smo

Comment: The problem is, there is nothing on their API that allows non client side work, unfortunately. Each API User ID search takes ~4seconds. 1000 users is >80 minutes

Answer (score 5):

You can use wonderfull method in `Parallel` class: `Parallel.For` static method. It will run every iteration of your loop in parallel, thus speeding up your program.

[Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.7.2)

In order to use that method, you need to refactor your code a little bit, so it could be run in parallel: it's better to avoid sharing data between threads and you share some variables over thread if you use `Parallel.For`, those variables are `getNames` and `LBItem`:

```
LeaderboardList.Add(new LeaderboardItem
{
    Rank = place,
    Name = (new GetNames(item["run"]["players"])).names,
    Time = time
};
```

You could use above instead of separately creating objects and assigning them to shared variables.

Comment: I use `getNames.names` inside the loop, and then add the `LBItem` object to the public list `LeaderboardList`. The loop works exactly as it should.
Edit: I will loop into `Parallel.For` thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @SirRufo Ok, should be OK now :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn depending on the implementation `Parallel.For` will require the `LeaderboardList` to become a thread-safe collection so the OP will have to change `List<T>` to a `ConcurrentBag<T>`